# Error 500 Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 34

Tags: javascript, java

I am creating a small website as a hobby, I am having issues in the registration form where the fields don't seem to be adding up to my SQL database.  I can pull all users no problem.

I believe the problem is with the fields not matching as it give me a message saying that there is no value specified for parameter 34

Please find my code below for:

- UserDAO (java)
- javascript
- SQL

```
    public User create(User users) {
        Connection c = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        try {
            c = DbConnector.getConnection();                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
            ps = c.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO tblmembers "
                    + "memberId,"//1
                    + "memberName,"//2
                    + "memberSurname,"//3
                    + "memberAddress,"//4
                    + "memberTown,"//5
                    + "memberCounty,"//6
                    + "memberPostCode,"//7
                    + "memberCountry,"//8
                    + "memberDocumentType,"//9
                    + "memberIdNumber,"//10
                    + "memberExpiryDate,"//11
                    + "memberIssuedBy,"//12
                    + "memberIssuePlace,"//13
                    + "memberDayOfBirth,"//14
                    + "memberMonthOfBirth,"//15
                    + "memberYearOfBirth,"//16
                    + "memberJobTitle,"//17
                    + "memberNationality,"//18
                    + "memberPhone1,"//19
                    + "memberPhone2,"//20
                    + "memberStatus,"//21
                    + "memberMaritalStatus,"//22
                    + "memberGender,"//23
                    + "memberSocialMedia,"//24
                    + "memberEmail,"//25
                    + "memberPassword,"//26
                    + "memberSecurityQuestion,"//27
                    + "memberSecurityQuestionAnswer,"//28
                    + "memberTransactionCount,"//29
                    + "memberLoginCount,"//30
                    + "memberPreferredPaymentType,"//31
                    + "memberSecurityId,"//32
                    + "memberNickname,"//33
                    + "agentId,)"//34
                    + "VALUES    (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,"
                                +"?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,"
                                +"?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,"
                                +"?,?,?,?)",
                    new String[] { "memberId" }
                                );
            
            ps.setString(1, users.getMemberName());
            ps.setString(2, users.getMemberSurname());
            ps.setString(3, users.getMemberAddress());
            ps.setString(4, users.getMemberTown());
            ps.setString(5, users.getMemberCounty());
            ps.setString(6, users.getMemberPostCode());
            ps.setString(7, users.getMemberCountry());
            ps.setString(8, users.getMemberDocumentType());
            ps.setString(9, users.getMemberIdNumber());
            ps.setString(10, users.getMemberExpiryDate());
            ps.setString(11, users.getMemberIssuedBy());
            ps.setString(12, users.getMemberIssuePlace());
            ps.setInt(13, users.getMemberDayOfBirth());
            ps.setInt(14, users.getMemberMonthOfBirth());
            ps.setInt(15, users.getMemberYearOfBirth());
            ps.setString(16, users.getMemberJobTitle());
            ps.setString(17, users.getMemberNationality());
            ps.setInt(18, users.getMemberPhone1());
            ps.setInt(19, users.getMemberPhone2());
            ps.setString(20, users.getMemberStatus());
            ps.setString(21, users.getMemberMaritalStatus());
            ps.setString(22, users.getMemberGender());
            ps.setString(23, users.getMemberSocialMedia());
            ps.setString(24, users.getMemberEmail());
            ps.setString(25, users.getMemberPassword());
            ps.setString(26, users.getMemberSecurityQuestion());
            ps.setString(27, users.getMemberSecurityQuestionAnswer());
            ps.setInt(28, users.getMemberTransactionCount());
            ps.setInt(29, users.getMemberLoginCount());
            ps.setString(30, users.getMemberPreferredPaymentType());
            ps.setString(31, users.getMemberSecurityId());
            ps.setString(32, users.getMemberNickname());
            ps.setInt(33, users.getAgentId());
            ps.executeUpdate();
            ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
            rs.next();
            int memberId = rs.getInt(1);
            users.setMemberId(memberId);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            DbConnector.close(c);
        }
        return users;
    }


//Javascript
var rootURL = "http://localhost:8080/{database_name}/list/users";

function addUser() {
    
    var memberId = $('#memberId').val();
    var memberName = $('#memberName').val();
    var memberSurname = $('#memberSurname').val();
    var memberAddress = $('#memberAddress').val();
    var memberTown = $('#memberTown').val();
    var memberCounty = $('#memberCounty').val();
    var memberPostCode = $('#memberPostCode').val();
    var memberCountry = $('#memberCountry').val();
    var memberDocumentType = $('#memberDocumentType').val();
    var memberIdNumber = $('#memberIdNumber').val();
    var memberExpiryDate = $('#memberExpiryDate').val();
    var memberIssuedBy = $('#memberIssuedBy').val();
    var memberIssuePlace = $('#memberIssuePlace').val();
    var memberDayOfBirth = $('#memberDayOfBirth').val();
    var memberMonthOfBirth = $('#memberMonthOfBirth').val();
    var memberYearOfBirth = $('#memberYearOfBirth').val();
    var memberJobTitle = $('#memberJobTitle').val();
    var memberNationality = $('#memberNationality').val();
    var memberPhone1 = $('#memberPhone1').val();
    var memberPhone2 = $('#memberPhone2').val();
    var memberStatus = $('#memberStatus').val();
    var memberMaritalStatus = $('#memberMaritalStatus').val();
    var memberGender = $('#memberGender').val();
    var memberSocialMedia = $('#memberSocialMedia').val();
    var memberEmail = $('#memberEmail').val();
    var memberPassword = $('#memberPassword').val();
    var memberSecurityQuestion = $('#memberSecurityQuestion').val();
    var memberSecurityQuestionAnswer = $('#memberSecurityQuestionAnswer').val();
    var memberTransactionCount = $('#memberTransactionCount').val();
    var memberLoginCount = $('#memberLoginCount').val();
    var memberPreferredPaymentType = $('#memberPreferredPaymentType').val();
    var memberSecurityId = $('#memberSecurityId').val();
    var memberNickname = $('#memberNickname').val();
    var agentId = $('#agentId').val();
    
        
    } else {
        console.log('Adding New User... ');
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : rootURL,
            data : JSON.stringify({
                "memberName" : memberName,
                "memberSurname" : memberSurname,
                "memberAddress": memberAddress,
                "memberTown": memberTown,
                "memberCounty": memberCounty,
                "memberPostCode" : memberPostCode,
                "memberCountry": memberCountry,
                "memberDocumentType": memberDocumentType,
                "memberIdNumber": memberIdNumber,
                "memberExpiryDate": memberExpiryDate,
                "memberIssuedBy": memberIssuedBy,
                "memberIssuePlace": memberIssuePlace,
                "memberDayOfBirth" : memberDayOfBirth,
                "memberMonthOfBirth" : memberMonthOfBirth,
                "memberYearOfBirth" : memberYearOfBirth,
                "memberJobTitle": memberJobTitle,
                "memberNationality": memberNationality,
                "memberPhone1" : memberPhone1,
                "memberPhone2" : memberPhone2,
                "memberStatus": memberStatus,
                "memberMaritalStatus" : memberMaritalStatus,
                "memberGender": memberGender,
                "memberSocialMedia" : memberSocialMedia,
                "memberEmail" : memberEmail,
                "memberPassword": memberPassword,
                "memberSecurityQuestion": memberSecurityQuestion,
                "memberSecurityQuestionAnswer" : memberSecurityQuestionAnswer,
                "memberTransactionCount" : memberTransactionCount,
                "memberLoginCount": memberLoginCount,
                "memberPreferredPaymentType" : memberPreferredPaymentType,
                "memberSecurityId": memberSecurityId,
                "memberNickname" : memberNickname,
                "agentId" : agentId
            }),
            dataType : "json",
            contentType : "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

                alert('User created successfully');
                $('#memberId').val(data.id);
                
            },
            error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('Registration error...');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: *"agentId,)"//34* why is there a comma before this ending bracket? Parameter 34 starting from 0 or from 1? perhaps it thinks because of that loose comma that there is a 35th parameter (index 34 using 0 for the first).

Comment: Also *ps.setInt(33, users.getAgentId());
            ps.executeUpdate();* If you are using 1 as your starting index then why is this the 34th parameters. Perhaps you added a parameter in between and missed it here.

Should not your first parameter be the id? sounds like you have to add ps.Set...(1, users.getMemberId()) assuming such a function exists. The remaining ps.Sets need to be incremented by 1 for index.

Comment: Also, there is actually no `setSomething(34,...)` there. In fact, you don't do anything with your `memberID` and all the others are off by one.

Comment: And: Your query will not work. You dont have an opening parenthesis after `INSERT INTO tblmembers`.

Comment: Did you read the error message at all? The message is that value 34 is not being set. That is being confirmed when reading your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears that you likely added an id as the first parameter in your prepare statement `+ "memberId,"//1` but you did not follow up by binding the value of this parameter below in the region with *ps.setString an ps.setInt*.

### Scenario 1: Auto Generated Ids

Remove `+ "memberId,"//1`.

### Scenario 2: Manually set ids (often with UUID/GUID and similar)

You will want to keep `+ "memberId,"//1` but ensure that you add the appropriately indexed `ps.setString(1, users.getMemberId())` or `ps.setInt(1, users.getMemberId())` (*assuming that `getMemberId()` exists*) depending on the type of the id. The parameters being bound below it need to have their index incremented by 1.

That will get rid of the error in the title. However, myself and others have mentioned in the comments that there are other problems with the code that will likely lead to different errors once this particular error gets resolved.

Comment: Thank you, it turns out that I needed to remove the  + "memberId,"//1
I also added an opening parenthesis after INSERT INTO tblmembers.

with the first change I then had to remove on ? from the values in my SQL

its all working perfect now